# Get value by date

Tags: datetime, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a data frame `df`:

```
            PRICE
2004-03-19  36.250000
2004-03-20  36.237500
2004-03-21  36.225000
2004-03-22  36.212500
etc...
```

The index is of type:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2004-03-19', '2004-03-20', '2004-03-21', ...],       
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1691, freq='D')
```

I want to retrieve the `PRICE` at a certain day using `df[datetime.date(2004,3,19)]`. This is what pandas does:

> KeyError: datetime.date(2004, 3, 19)

The following works, but that can't be the way it is supposed to work:

`df[df.index.isin(pd.DatetimeIndex([datetime.date(2004,3,19)]))].PRICE.values[0]`

Comment: "Am I crazy?". I think that's for http://psychology.stackexchange.com .

Comment: More practically: I don't see the date 2004-03-18 in your example data (but the ellipsis hide data). Which is exactly what Pandas tells you as well.

Comment: Example is not as code. I am trying to retrieve a value at one of the existing dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the comparison is being performed for an exact match, as none of the times are `00:00:00` then no matches occur.

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html):

```
print df.loc[pd.DatetimeIndex(['2004-3-19'])]
            PRICE
2004-03-19  36.25
```

Or you can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), convert string `2004-3-19` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and get [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) of [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html):

```
print df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2004-3-19').date()]
PRICE    36.25
Name: 2004-03-19 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

If you need value of `PRICE`:

```
print df.loc[pd.DatetimeIndex(['2004-3-19']), 'PRICE']
2004-03-19    36.25
Name: PRICE, dtype: float64

print df.loc[pd.DatetimeIndex(['2004-3-19']), 'PRICE'].values[0]
36.25

print df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2004-3-19').date(), 'PRICE']
36.25
```

But if add `time` to `datetime`, [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) match:

```
print df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2004-3-19 00:00:00')]
PRICE    36.25
Name: 2004-03-19 00:00:00, dtype: float64

print df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2004-3-19 00:00:00'), 'PRICE']
36.25
```

Answer (score 1):

Your index appears to be timestamps, whereas you are trying to equate them to datetime.date objects.

Rather than trying to retrieve the price via `df[datetime.date(2004,3,19)]`, I would simply recommend `df['2004-3-19']`.

If you are intent on using datetime.date values, you should first convert the index.

```
df.index = [d.date() for d in df.index]
```